# Нужна помощь с двумерными массивами C++

Tags: c++, массивы

Нужно организовать проверку элементов двумерного массива по диагонали с рандомных координат, по аналогии с ходом коня в шахматах. Вот часть кода для одного слона. У меня он проверяет каждый столбец, нет идей как организовать проверку по диагонали.

```
for (int i = x[0]; i < n && i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = y[0]; j < n && j >= 0; j--) {
            if (a[i][j] == 9) {
                cout << "One black elephant is on the way" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = x[0]; i < n && i >= 0; i++) {

        for (int j = y[0]; j < n && j >= 0; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] == 9) {
                cout << "One black elephant is on the way" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = x[0]; i < n && i >= 0; i++) {

        for (int j = y[0]; j < n && j >= 0; j--) {
            if (a[i][j] == 9) {
                cout << "One black elephant is on the way" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = x[0]; i < n && i >= 0; i--) {

        for (int j = y[0]; j < n && j >= 0; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] == 9) {
                cout << "One black elephant is on the way" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
//x - введенная координата
//y - введенная координата
//n - конец матрицы
for(int i = x; i < n;i++){ //если ввести i-- пойдет в обратную сторону
       y-- //аналогично, выбираем сторону
}
if(...){
.......
}
if(y == 0){ //в случае, если идет в конец матрицы, проверяем на конец матрицы по Yку
break;
}
```